# Make Titanium Studio play a sound when the build is complete?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Whilst I'm waiting for TiStudio to build and re-launch the iOS Simulator or Android device I like to look out the window and stretch my eyes a bit, or worse quickly flick to Reddit.

The problem is (especially with Reddit) I can get distracted for longer than I wanted and waste time.. If I could attach a beep to a particular build event in TiStudio this would help..

Any ideas (this is a serious question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Titanium build hook, this is added to projects individually and allows you to get a notification with sound when build is done
https://gist.github.com/hanih/16cf2468825bbe4e27f3